# В каком случае у непривилегированного файла может быть выставлен эффективный файловый бит? (POSIX capabilities)

Tags: linux, posix

Я пытаюсь разобраться в принципе работы POSIX-capabilities, если конкретнее, в их преобразовании при выполнении execve().

```
       P'(ambient)     = (file is privileged) ? 0 : P(ambient)

       P'(permitted)   = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) |
                         (F(permitted) & P(bounding)) | P'(ambient)

       P'(effective)   = F(effective) ? P'(permitted) : P'(ambient)

       P'(inheritable) = P(inheritable)    [i.e., unchanged]

       P'(bounding)    = P(bounding)       [i.e., unchanged]

   where:

       P()   denotes the value of a thread capability set before the
             execve(2)

       P'()  denotes the value of a thread capability set after the
             execve(2)

       F()   denotes a file capability set
```

Судя по [документации](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) сначала происходит проверка, является ли файл привилегированным. Там же написано, что привилегированный файл - это файл, имеющий capabilities или setuid/setguid биты.

```
A privileged file is one that has capabilities or has the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit set
```

Далее происходит проверка, выставлен ли файловый эффективный бит. Возникает 4 ситуации:

- Файл привилегированный и имеет эффективный бит -> рассчитываем новые capabilities, т.к. файл имеет файловые capabilities
- Файл привилегированный и не имеет эффективного бита -> не выставляем capabilities вообще (т.к. файл все равно запущен из-под root)
- Файл не привилегированный и не имеет эффективного бита -> P'(effective) = P(ambient)

Непонятен только 4й случай, когда файл непривилегированный и имеет эффективный бит. У него нет capabilities, так что

1. разве он может вообще иметь единицу в эффективном бите?
2. даже если он и имеет 1 в эффективном бите, нули в файловых наборах capabilities превратят выражение

```
(P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) | (F(permitted) & P(bouning)) | P(ambient)
```

в

```
P(ambient)
```

Что не имеет смысла (или я его не вижу). Где-то я ошибаюсь, но не могу понять, где.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, описанная ситуация не может возникнуть, так как эффективный флаг не может быть выставлен, если наследуемый и доступный наборы пусты:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_chown=ep mybinary
$ getcap mybinary
mybinary = cap_chown+ep
$ sudo setcap cap_chown=e mybinary
$ getcap mybinary
mybinary =
```

Ответ взят со [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686015/how-can-an-unprivileged-file-have-an-enabled-effective-bit-posix-capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

> проверка, является ли файл привилегированным

Файл не может быть **привилегированным** или **не привилегированным**. Эти понятия относятся к **процессу**. Грубо говоря, процесс будет привилегированным, если его запустил привилегированный пользователь. Для более строго понимания, читаем *man*:

```
man 7 capabilities

Для  выполнения  проверки  прав  доступа в обычных реализациях UNIX 
процессы разделяют на две категории: привилегированные (ID эффективного
пользователя равен 0, как  у  суперпользователя или  root),  
и  не  привилегированные  (ID  эффективного  пользователя  не  
равен  нулю). Для привилегированных  процессов  все  проверки 
прав  в  ядре   не   выполняются,   а   для   не привилегированных  
процессов выполняется полная проверка на основе мандатов процесса 
(обычно, эффективного UID, эффективного GID и списка дополнительных групп).

В ядре Linux начиная с версии 2.2, все привилегии, обычно связываемые  
с  суперпользователем, разделены на несколько частей, называемых 
мандатами (capabilities), которые можно разрешать и запрещать независимо 
друг от друга. Мандаты являются атрибутом нити.
```

Comment: Не понимаю, как это относится к вопросу. Существование привилегированных потоков никак не противоречит возможности существования файлов, условно называемыми привилегированными и используемых при расчете capabilities (мандатов)

Comment: @Ekaterina -"файлов, условно называемыми привилегированными" - это круто!
- "как это относится к вопросу" - К вопросу относится *man 7 capabilities* - там всё прописано.

Comment: Я читала _man 7 capabilities_ и там действительно написано про привилегированные потоки. Эту часть документации я поняла, к ней вопросов нет. Я же прошу разъяснений по поводу преобразования мандатов при выполнении execve. В той же самой документации эта часть находится немного ниже.

Comment: @Ekaterina Вот Ваш изначальный вопрос: "разве он может вообще иметь единицу в эффективном бите?". Может быть я не правильно вас понял, но мне кажется. что под "эффективным битом" Вы понимаете setuid/setguid биты. Так ? Но эти биты - атрибуты **файла**, а не процесса. Они хранятся в файловой системе, на диске, а не создаются динамически. Они гораздо старше понятия *capabilities* и означают наследование прав доступаидёт  не от текущего пользователя. а от владельца этого исполняемого файла.

Comment: @Ekaterina Т.е. если некий ELF пытается очистить /user/bin то он может это сделать, если (1) у этого  ELF взведён бит *setuid*  (2) хозяином этого ELA-а является root (3) я знаю пароль root. И процессы здесь ни коим боком....

Comment: Нет, эффективный бит это часть **файловых** мандатов. У файла есть три типа мандатов - effective, permitted и inheritable. Однако эффективный мандат, в отличие от мандатов потока и аналогичных им permitted и inheritable мандатов файла, является не набором битов, а битом. В вопросе я указала, что судя по документации, привилегированный файл - это файл, имеющий capabilities или setuid/setguid биты.

Comment: Ну ладно, значит Вы лучше меня в этом разбираетесь :-)